# What book is about a planet of feline humans?

Tags: story-identification, books

Does anyone know the title of a book about a planet with cat-like people who call themselves humans, and they keep humans as slaves/pets?

They live in the shadow of a planetary ring and eventually discover the bright side of the planet where human astronauts are colonizing the planet. (The colonists didn't think the planet was inhabited by sentient beings since the feline "humans" live in the shadow of the planet's ring which disrupts sensors.

The human slaves/pets are descendants of some of the original colonists who got lost in a storm or something.)

Any help would be appreciated -- it's driving me crazy that I can't remember the name of this book.

Comment: Is it one of the answers to [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22973/alien-race-cat-type-people-bounty-hunters) by any chance? Or maybe the same story being described in [this unanswered question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/106603/looking-for-a-trilogy-of-books-by-british-author-military-space-operatic-with-f)?

Comment: Also, can you remember any more details? Like when you read the book, whether it was a novel or short story, what language it was written in ... any little thing can help!

Comment: Actually, a few hours after I posted this I finally found the title from extensive searching at Amazon -- it's called "Godsfire" by Cynthia Felice.

Answer (score 3):

Found it! Godsfire by Cynthia Felice.

Comment: Good job on finding this! Don't forget to accept your own answer so this question is marked as being solved :-)